# How to calculate three three shifts in 24 hours in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate three shifts in 24 hours. I wrote a case expression to get the three shifts. I am getting morning and evening shift but getting null values for night shift, i.e. the time between 23:00:00 and 07:00:00. Here is the code, any suggestions?

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 07 AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 12 THEN  ' Morning'
WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 12 AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 23 THEN  ' Evening'
WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 23 AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 07 THEN  ' Night' END AS Shift_Type
```

Comment: The last condition `DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 23 AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 07` should be a `OR`

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you. another quick question further to that. Isn't the 'Night Shift' i.e. from '23:00:00' to '07:00:00' moving to the next day? In which case, is my case expression correct?

Comment: You are only comparing the hour, not the day, so that fact that it overlaps doesn't matter for your query. However it depends what you are ultimately trying to do, which we don't know.

Comment: @Squirrel Thank you. You are right, I checked the time when a patient was admitted and discharged from Acute Care Unit and the result set shows the results as per the query. i.e. the patient was admitted at '2022-09-27 03:56:00.0000000' and  discharged at '2022-09-27 04:32:00.0000000' and according to my case expression it comes up as 'Night' in my 'Shift_Type' column.  Could you please suggest how my code would look like if I was comparing it by the day?

Comment: What does "Could you please suggest how my code would look like if I was comparing it by the day?" mean? You need to provide sample data and desired results - at this stage I would suggest a new question, since your original question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible for a single hour value to be **BOTH** >= 23 **AND** also < 7, that is why you must use OR when making the comparison for night shift. Unlike the other shifts the single hour value can be (BOTH >= 7 and < 12) or (BOTH >= 12 and < 23)

So:

```
insert into ct (InPACU) values
  ('2023-09-01 07:30:00')
, ('2023-09-01 12:30:00')
, ('2023-09-01 17:30:00')
, ('2023-09-01 23:30:00');


SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 07
            AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 12
            THEN ' Morning'
        WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 12
            AND DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 23
            THEN ' Evening'
        WHEN DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) >= 23
            OR DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) < 07 -- OR here
            THEN ' Night'
        END AS Shift_Type
     , DATEPART(hh, ct.InPACU) hour
FROM ct
```

| Shift_Type | Hour |
| --- | --- |
| Morning | 7 |
| Evening | 12 |
| Evening | 17 |
| Night | 23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k8FVPMtD)

**btw** you could use `ELSE 'Night'` instead.

Comment: No problem. Do you know how to "accept" an answer? This indicates to all users (esp those looking for a similar answer) that there is an answer.

Comment: Can you suggest how do I calculate the ''average number of patients within a particular shift''? i.e. using the three 'case' expressions as well as this line of code. `sum(datediff(hour, ct.InPACU, ct.DischargeFromPACU)) / 24.0 `

Comment: These comment boxes are wholly inadequate for full answers, and you will get more from stackoverflow by opening new questions rather than attempting a virtual conversation - if for no other reason than a new question will get 100s of eyes on it quickly - but a comment here will get very few and it could be days before I return here.